# Amount of information a row adds to a data set

Tags: categorical-data, many-categories

I'm sorry if this is vaguely worded, but I'm looking for a way to score each row in a dataset by, essentially, the amount of information that that row adds - or the uniqueness of that row in the data set.
For example, say I have a table with 3 rows and two columns:

1. col1: a, col2: b
2. col1: c, col2: d
3. col1: a, col2: d

I want a metric that basically says that rows 1 and 2 are equally weighted and 3 has a lower weight. My thinking behind this is somewhat along the lines of - if I wanted to list all the sets that contained all the values for each column, then I would have 2 sets {1,2} and {1,2,3}. Rows 1 and 2 are elements in both sets, but row 3 is only in one of the sets, so in some way it should have half the weight.

Is there a way to scale this or a different sort of metric around the uniqueness of each row when all of the fields are categorical?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe clustering based on cosine distance can help. After you cluster all rows, you can post analyze the ones most distant from their clusters centeroids.

Comment: In a dataset it is usually understood that different columns can have different datatypes, so that it won't make sense in general to compare `a` or `c` to either of `b` or `d`.  Your question, however, uses set notation to designate the rows, as if the columns did not matter and a row is just a set (which has no order).  Could you please clarify your meaning?  Some additional examples of the values of the intended metric would also be helpful, because it will help narrow the (currently huge) range of possible solutions.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the row is a set - I just didn't know a better way to display the data. In the example, a,c,a is one column and b,d,d is another column. I edited it, please let me know if it is clearer

Comment: Now your description appears to be at odds with your calculations. The subsets of the rows {1,2,3} containing all values of column 1 are {1,2} and {2,3}, while the subsets containing all values of column 2 are {1,2} and {1,3}. Your calculation still seems somehow to be throwing all the values in *both* columns together, rather than operating on "each column" as you write. Presenting a set of examples, rather than one very limited example, may help clarify your meaning and overcome any ambiguities in your description.

Comment: This seems to match with my description... Your sets are looking at column by column which is fine. And since {1,2} is in both of your set-of-subsets, then it contains all values for both columns. Only other subset that does that is {1,2,3}.

Comment: I’m wondering if leverage might be part of what you’re looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)

Comment: @Dave - is there a relatively easily calculable leverage metric for categorical variables?

Comment: Maybe try MDS multidimensional scaling on the rows? and then look for outlying/atypical values?